# Pass parameters to location.href in javascript instead if HEADER()

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am new to wordpress.

I have tried the following code

```
    header("Location: $location", true, $status);
```

I want to redirect the page to particular page and i am getting this kind of error

```
    "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at   /home/content/c/l/a/clareb23/html/client4/wp-content/plugins/featured-articles-lite/main.php:773) in /home/content/c/l/a/clareb23/html/client4/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 870"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: if you are working in wordpress then you should better use wp_redirect()  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: i am using `wp_redirect()`, but it is conflicting with the plugin code...

Answer (score 1):

**Based on comment**

You can do it like this:

```
<script>
  window.location = '<?php echo $location?>?myvar=true&status=<?php echo $status?>';
</script>
```

---

Make sure that you do not echo/print anything on screen before `header(...)` statement and that there is no whitespace before opening php tag eg `<?php`. It is also good practice to put `exit()` after `header()` function.

Comment: yes, but i don't want to use header(...), instead i want to redirect the page with javascript and want to pass "true" and "$status" as parameters...

Comment: you are right... but in my case it is not working. i am not fetching the parameters anywhere else, i am just redirecting to the specified page. This "?myvar=true&status=<?php echo $status?>" will pass these parameters as the query string. There is no way to get out of here...